# Conditionally run Jenkins stage on a different slave/workspace otherwise use existing slave/workspace

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

I'm trying to run a stage of my pipeline on another slave conditionally. But this isn't working correctly. The main pipeline runs with label `ecs-slave` (I'm using container slaves).

I want to be able to save if X run this stage on a different slave with label X otherwise continue as usually with the current slave.

What happens instead is Jenkins provisions another NEW slave with label ecs-slave instead of using the current one.

```
pipeline {
    agent {
        node {
            label 'ecs-slaves'
        }
    }

    stages {
        stage('ssss') {
            // Regarless of whether the label is different or the same (ecs-slaves) jenkins provisions a _new_ slave
            agent {
                node {
                    label "${(var == 'blahblah') ? 'ecs-slaves' : 'some-others-slave'}"
                }
            }

            environment{...}
            steps{
              ....
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The if/else is encapsulated in the variable block (`{}`). You just want **var** inside those brackets.

```
node {
  label "(${var} == 'blahblah') ? 'ecs-slaves' : 'some-others-slave'"
}
```

There is another problem. The way your pipeline is laid out will generate a new slave no matter what is in the stage `ssss`, even if the names are the same. You want to use a when block to avoid this. Check out [this example](https://jenkins.io/blog/2017/01/19/converting-conditional-to-pipeline/), which I will provide below.

```
pipeline {
    agent {
        node {
            label 'ecs-slaves'
        }
    }

    parameters {
        choice(
            choices: ["${env.NODE_NAME}", 'other-slaves'],
            description: '',
            name: 'RUN_ON_SLAVE'
        )
    }

    stages {
        // Trigger this only when running on other slaves and set a new node
        stage('ssss') {
            when {
                expression { params.RUN_ON_SLAVE == 'other-slaves' }
            }
            // Regardless of whether the label is different or the same (ecs-slaves) jenkins provisions a _new_ slave
            agent {
                node {
                    label 'other-slaves'
                }
            }

            environment{...}
            steps{
              ....
            }
        }
        // Trigger this when 'ssss' is not triggered and don't run on a new node
        stage('ssst') {
            when {
                expression { params.RUN_ON_SLAVE == "${env.NODE_NAME}" }
            }

            environment{...}
            steps{
                ....
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thats what im trying avoid. i want to use the _same_ stage

Answer (score 0):

Multiple build executors on a single ECS container agent is something not supported currently. Since you have already defined `ecs-slaves` as the agent at the top-level of your pipeline, the container spawned there will remain locked until the end of the pipeline. So, the stage `ssss` will either remain indefinitely queued (theoretically) for lack of another executor on the same container, or it will spawn another container with the same label as in your case.